# Event Hub Chart time wrong in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have a working Event Hub which I am sending data to fine with a client application

However, when I go to the Azure overview for the event hub the time is 1 hour behind

I am assuming this is related to GMT/BST

How can I fix this?

Cheers

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Hmm this may just be a display issue with the overall chart as the version for showing activity shows the correct time